# Sending Inline images in email with JavaMailSenderImpl

Tags: java, spring, liferay, jakarta-mail

Hi for sending email I'm using `JavaMailSenderImpl` and creating a `message` With the Help of `MimeMessageHelper.`

Now I can send Inline images in email which are present on my localmachine.

```
c:\temp\img.jpg



FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File("c:/Temp/img.jpg"));
helper.addInline("identifier1234",res);
```

and I'm using it in the `<img src>` as

```
 src ='cid:identifier1234'
```

But now I want to send Images that are not present on my local machine, Images are hosted on server. and images are only accessible through some URL(Actually the Images are stored on LifeRay DB) so is there a way to do that ? please help  and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are just two ways.

1. Content of the Image can be part of the email (as attachment) and you can refer via cid. The way you have done. If the file is external, you/some library will need to download it and package it into the mail body.
2. External images can be linked via `<img src="" />` tag and sent as an html email. Image is downloaded and displayed during the page render time, by the browser/mail client. Here the mail content is not heavy, since the image is not part of the mail content. Browser/Mail clients will also have an option to show/hide the image.